# How to query with multiple conditions and those conditions are dependent

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

Suppose **"A001", "A002", "A003"** in **symptoms_N** means **"nose allergic"**

Suppose **"Z001", "Z002"** in **symptoms_N** means **"nose cancer"**

I want to find those who got **nose cancer** AND the had got **nose allergic** before getting cancer.

For example, the following 2 records hit the target I want.

I can inferred **Jack** got "nose cancer" on 2015-04-02,

and he had got "nose allergic" on 2011-04-02.

I can find the **nose allergic** records with **$or aggregation** operator. like `db.collection.find({"$or": OR_CONDITIONS})`

I have no idea how to finish the compounded conditions query in MongoDB.

```
{
    "name": "Jack",
    "symptoms_1": "B00 ",
    "symptoms_2": "A001 ",
    "symptoms_3": "     ",
    "datetime": "2011-04-02"
},

....


{
    "name": "Jack",
    "symptoms_1": "",
    "symptoms_2": "",
    "symptoms_3": "Z001",
    "datetime": "2015-04-02"
},
```

Answer (score 0):

you put the conditions inside an [ {}, {}, {}, {}] array (since an array is valid json).

```
db.inventory.find( { $or: [ { "symptom_1": "Z001" }, {"symptom_2": "Z002" }] })
```

in fact, you might be seeking the $in operator that works on a common field

```
db.collection.find({ "symptom_1": { $in: ["Z001", "Z002", "A001", "A002", "A003"]});
```

and it seems you want comb thru all symptom fields so use both $or and $in as such

```
db.collection.find({$or:
[
 {"symptom_1": { $in: ["Z001", "Z002", "A001", "A002", "A003"]}},
 {"symptom_2": { $in: ["Z001", "Z002", "A001", "A002", "A003"]}} ,
  ...
 ]} );
```

the braces might be mismatched but start off with that.

Comment: I know it. but How to add dependent conditions that can query someone had got alergic first then got the cancer later ?

Comment: then you need to look at aggregations not simple a find. your nose cancer, nose allergy is confounding the issue. try "A001", "A002", "A003" means X and ... means Y or simply drop the multiple conditions and use A001 vs Z001